# Cannot join friends, windows-key+g does nothing

Tags: pc, sea-of-thieves

When a friend invites me to a game, I get a popup on the side of the screen saying "*Press* <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> *to join*". However, pressing that does nothing.

I tried reinstalling the "XBox Game Bar" app from the Windows Store, which made things worse - not only does the key combo still do nothing, but I also no longer see invites.  Ahh!

**How can I join my friends?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we figured out a solution, but it's not great.

1. **[Upgrade to Windows 10 v1903](https://pureinfotech.com/upgrade-windows-10-1903-may-2019-update/)**. This update came out last month, and causes a ton of issues.  But unfortunately it's necessary for step 2.
2. From the Microsoft Store app, **download the [XBox (Beta)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/xbox-beta/9mv0b5hzvk9z?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) app**.
3. From the "XBox (Beta)" app, go to **social --> friends --> right-click the host --> join game**

It's insane that you need to update your computer to a broken OS version and download a separate app just to join a friend's game, but there you have it.